# How do I resolve Verilog simulation error: "Too many port connections. Expected 8, found 9" in ModelSim

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to build an 8-bit multiplier in Verilog, but I keep running in to this weird error when I go to simulate my module's test bench. It says:

```
Too many port connections. Expected 8, found 9
```

This doesn't really make any sense seeing as how both the module AND the test bench have 9 variables listed. Any help will be much appreciated!

**Multiplier Module**

```
module my8bitmultiplier (output [15:0] O, output Done, Cout, input [7:0] A, B, input Load, Clk, Reset, Cin);

    reg Done;
    reg [1:0] state;
    reg [7:0] A_reg, B_reg;
    reg [15:0] A_temp, B_temp, O_temp, O_reg;

    my16bitadder Adding(O_temp, Cout,A_temp,B_temp, Cin);

    always@(posedge Clk)
        begin

        if(Reset) assign state = {2'b00};
        case(state)

        0:
            if(Load)
            begin
                A_reg = A;
                B_reg = B;
                O_reg = A_reg;
                state = 1;
            end
        1:
            begin
                A_temp = A_reg;
                B_temp = O_reg;
                B_reg = B_reg - 1;
                state = 2;
            end
        2:
            begin
                O_reg = O_temp;
                if(B_temp)
                begin
                    state = 1;
                end
                else
                begin
                    state = 3;
                    Done = 1'b1;
                end
            end
        3:
            begin
                Done = 1'b0;
                state = 0;
            end

        endcase

    end

endmodule
```

**Testbench**

```
module my8bitmultiplier_tb;

reg Load, Clk, Reset, Cin;
reg [7:0] A, B;
wire [15:0] O;
wire Done, Cout;

my8bitmultiplier dut(O, Done, Cout, A, B, Load, Clk, Reset, Cin);

always #5 Clk = ~Clk;
initial
begin
A = 8'b10;
B = 8'b10;
Load = 1;
Cin = 0;
#10 Load = 0;
#3000 A = 8'd100;
#3000 B = 8'd100;
#3000 Load = 1;
#3010 Load = 0;
#6000 A = 8'd150;
#6000 B = 8'd150;
#6000 Load = 1;
#6000 Load = 0;
begin

$display ($time,"A= %d     B= %d     O=%d ", A, B, O);

end
#10000 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run you code on another simulator, I get a more helpful warning message:

```
    reg Done;
           |
xmvlog: *W,ILLPDX : Multiple declarations for a port not allowed in module with ANSI list of port declarations (port 'Done') [12.3.4(IEEE-2001)].
```

The warning goes away when I delete this line:

```
reg Done;
```

and change:

```
module my8bitmultiplier (output [15:0] O, output Done, Cout, input [7:0] A, B, input Load, Clk, Reset, Cin);
```

to:

```
module my8bitmultiplier (output [15:0] O, output reg Done, Cout, input [7:0] A, B, input Load, Clk, Reset, Cin);
```

Perhaps that solves your problem on modelsim.  You can also try your code on different simulators on edaplayground.  You will sometimes get more helpful messages.